# Are there sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that cannot be in the domain of any finitely additive, isometry-invariant, nontrivial measure?

Tags: measure-theory

The Vitali construction implies (given AC) the existence of sets of reals such that for any nontrivial, translation-invariant, countably additive measure on the real line, those sets are nonmeasurable and have inner measure 0.

By contrast, Banach showed that there exists a nontrivial, translation-invariant, finitely additive measure defined on all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  However the Banach-Tarski paradox shows that there is no nontrivial, finitely additive, isometry-invariant measure on $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined on all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Moreover, it tells us that there are some five-membered collections of regions in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that any nontrivial, isometry-invariant measure on $\mathbb{R}^3$ must treat at least one of those regions as nonmeasurable.  However it is not immediately obvious (at least to me) that it implies that any single *one* of those regions is forced be nonmeasurable, or that any of them is forced to have inner measure 0.

So, my question is:

- Are there regions $X$ such that for any nontrivial, finitely additive, isometry-invariant measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$, $X$ is not $\mu$-measurable and has inner $\mu$-measure 0?

And if the answer to that one is ‘no’:

- Are there regions $X$ such that for any nontrivial, finitely additive, isometry-invariant measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$, $X$ is not $\mu$-measurable?
- Are there finite sets of regions $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ such that for any nontrivial, finitely additive, isometry-invariant measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$, at least one $X_i$ is not $\mu$-measurable and has inner $\mu$-measure 0?